# Is there an util function to translate a Supplier which throws Exception into Optional in Java8?

Tags: java-8, option-type, vavr

I'm using vavr, and find there is no such util in `Option`, is there a similar handy util in any other package in java8?

```
public final class Utils {
    public static <T> Option<T> optionOfThrowableSupplier(Supplier<T> supplier){
        try {
            T x = supplier.get();
            return Option.some(x);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return Option.none();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Callable` might be more suitable for "a `Supplier` that might throw an `Exception`"

Answer (score 1):

Why not just:

```
Try.of(() -> "throwable supplier").toOption()
```

?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seems such utility exist. I suggest to create a `Supplier` wrapper class to solve this problem, which convert the given `Supplier<T>` to `Supplier<Option<T>>` and the `get` method will return `Option.none();` when exception is thrown.

```java
import java.util.function.Supplier;

import io.vavr.control.Option;

public class HandleExceptionOptionSupplier<T> implements Supplier<Option<T>> {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Supplier<String> noErrorSupplier = () -> {
            return "Success";
        };
        Supplier<String> errorSupplier = () -> {
            throw new RuntimeException("");
        };
        System.out.println(new HandleExceptionOptionSupplier<String>(noErrorSupplier).get()
                .getOrElse("No element"));
        System.out.println(new HandleExceptionOptionSupplier<String>(errorSupplier).get()
                .getOrElse("No element"));
    }

    private final Supplier<T> throwableSupplier;

    /**
     * return {@link Option#some(Object)} when the throwableSupplier has no error,
     * when there is exception, return {@link Option#none()}
     */
    @Override
    public Option<T> get() {
        try {
            T value = throwableSupplier.get();
            return Option.some(value);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return Option.none();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param throwableSupplier the supplier to wrap
     */
    public HandleExceptionOptionSupplier(Supplier<T> throwableSupplier) {
        this.throwableSupplier = throwableSupplier;
    }
}
```